# 'datetime.date' object is not callable

Tags: python, django

I have a model with a `date` field and a following method:

```
class Pm(models.Model):
    mydate = models.DateField()

    @property
    def due_date(self):
        today = timezone.localtime(timezone.now()).date()
        if self.mydate < today:
            return today
        else:
            return self.mydate
```

How can I order `myModel.objects.all()` based on the return of `due_date` function?
I tried:

```
qs = sorted(Pm.objects.all(), key=lambda a: a.due_date(), reverse=True)
```

but it returns error:

```
'datetime.date' object is not callable
```

**UPDATE**
Based on Sami's suggestion:

```
@staticmethod
    def due_date(obj):
        today = timezone.localtime(timezone.now()).date()
        if obj.pm_date < today:
            return today
        else:
            return obj.pm_date

qs = sorted(Pm.objects.all(), key=Pm.due_date, reverse=True)
```

Seems to work, except it returns a list instead of a queryset.

What method should I use to get a queryset?

Comment: Well, you marked it as a property, so don't call it.

Comment: Your error says you are trying to "call" a date. Try dropping the parentheses and see if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I wouldn't sort it in python. For two reasons:

- Database should do it better/faster than python
- The property makes a lot of dates not sortable: everything that is older than today is made equal. It serves no purpose, especially without a secondary sort field.

And since you ultimately want a queryset, just keep it simple:

```py
qs = Pm.objects.order_by('-mydate')
# Now we can display the due date property when we render things:
for pm in qs:
   print(pm.due_date)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to make your method due_date a static method or separate it from model, method gets the obj and return a date, and then use this method in sorted method. Something like this

```
def due_date(obj):
        today = timezone.localtime(timezone.now()).date()
        if obj.date < today:
            return today
        else:
            return obj.date
qs = sorted(Pm.objects.all(), key=due_date, reverse=True)
```

If you make this method static in the Model class, then use it as:

```
qs = sorted(Pm.objects.all(), key=PM.due_date, reverse=True)
```

Otherwise you need to annotate and then use order_by of the queryset.
[annotation with conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/)
[F-expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions)

something like this (it may not be the exact solution but you need to do something like this):

```
from django.db.models import Case, DateField, Value, When
qs = Pm.objects.annotate(
    due_date=Case(
        When(date__lt=today, then=Value(today)),
        default=F("date"),
        output_field=DateField(),
    )
)
qs.order_by("due_date")
```

Comment: Then I think you need to annotate the due_date in queryset using conditional expressions. And then use order_by on due_date, I added a reference link in my answer.